# Retrieve final email sent to subscriber

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, email

I'm trying to understand whether it's possible to retrieve the final email sent to a subscriber via the API.  We would like to import these into our system to link back to the subscribers in our own database for our users who don't have access to the exact target UI to view.

I can see that I can retrieve the 'Send' objects containing the preview URL, however our sends usually contain a lot of dynamic contents targeting multiple languages.  This renders the preview unusable for our purposes.

Is there a way to retrieve the final emails sent to a subscriber through Exact Target via the API?

Kind Regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, ExactTarget does not store copies of emails sent to each individual subscriber. You can use tracking data to get the last email sent, but you can only retrieve the raw version of the email, not the specific built version per subscriber.

Comment: It is possible to archive emails through the BCC feature. Essentially, each send to each subscriber is BCCed to another email address. This BCC email could then be processed outside of ExactTarget.